# Aliases in .bash_profile not working properly

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I have been trying to alter the .bash_profile that is in my root directory, but have been running into some problems. I am on OS X, Yosemite, on a Macbook Pro. As I understand it, the .bash_profile file contains the script that is called automatically whenever the Terminal app is opened and the bash shell starts. 
This is what I currently have written in that file:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This works perfectly fine. However, I want to add an alias (right underneath the above two lines) as follows:

```
alias test='cd ..'
```

However, when I save this and start up the Terminal, I get the following message:

```
-bash: alias: ..": not found
```

Replacing the single quotes with double quotes doesn't help, nor does taking them away altogether. Curiously however, the following alias works:

```
alias c=clear
```

When I type c into the terminal, it clear the screen, as you would expect. However, if I instead entered this line with quotes in the bash profile as:

```
alias c='clear'
```

Then I will get the following whenever I enter c into the Terminal:

```
-bash: 'clear': command not found
```

Note that I do not get an error message on startup for this alias.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a setting I need to change somewhere to get aliases to work properly? I have seen previous examples of aliases and they simply do not work for me.

Comment: Which editor are you using to modify the file? If it's using something equivalent to Word's "smart quotes", that would explain this behavior.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the error messages (particularly, the latter one) straight from your terminal prompt, or did you retype it? If you retyped, it might be helpful if you went the copy-and-paste route, so we can check the exact characters used.

Comment: Sounds like your quotes are funny.  The single quote should be an ASCII apostrophe (ASCII 39) and not some sort of fancy shmancy curly quotes.

Comment: I opened the file in Text Edit. Are you saying that it's possible this problem is due to my editor?

Comment: That's exactly what they are saying.

Comment: You shouldn't put aliases into .bash_profile. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36484388/4694621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alias defined in .bash\_profile not working in OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484139/alias-defined-in-bash-profile-not-working-in-os-x)

Answer (score 67):

It looks like shell is not accessing your .bash_profile when logging via terminal.

`.bash_profile` is a config file of bash shell. When bash shell starting, shell will execute the commands in `.bash_profile`. But there are many kinds of shells, and different shells execute different config file.

Terminal is a software to receive user input, shell will execute commands.You can use `cat /etc/shells` to list acceptable shells. For example：

```
$ cat /etc/shells
/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
```

The default shell is bash shell on Mac OX. But if you have installed zsh, the default shell is zsh, when zsh shell starting, shell will find out the file named `.zshrc`, and execute the commands in `.zshrc`.

You can use `echo $SHELL` to determine the current shell:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

```
-> echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

If your default shell is zsh, `.bash_profile` don't work. The config file of zsh is `.zshrc`. And I guess your problem is that your default shell is not bash shell. For example, if your default shell is zsh, you should config the `.zshrc` , just add

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

or other config to `~/.zshrc`.

Then `source ~/.zshrc`, and the config will work immediately.

Comment: The command to view the list of shells is: 
```
cat /etc/shells 
``` 
and not 
```
cat /etc/shell
```

Comment: @SulavTimsina You are right, thanks.

Comment: This has been confusing me for so long, why my aliases were not working correctly. Thank you much!

Comment: to change back to bash and .bass_profile run:
chsh -s /bin/bash

Comment: Ahh. One must execute `source ...` on the profile to make it effective. One would think logging in and out of the shell would do it, but, alas, something more arcane is appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

Wrapping the command with double quotation worked for me. I was trying with every possible way mentioned in this thread and none of them worked. Then I replaced single quote to double and that worked.

```
    alias mysql_start="sudo /path/to/server/mysql.server start"
```

Comment: Single quotes *should* work the same (or actually better, a lot of the time; double quotes offer weaker protection of the string between them; so any dollar sign, backtick, literal double quote, or backslash will need to be backslash-escaped when you switch from single to double quotes).

Answer (score 10):

For me, it didn't work in the same terminal. I had to open a new one to get it work.

Comment: Editing the file changes it for future shells, but the one you are already running will not read the config file again unless you specifically ask it to. You can `source ~/.bash_profile` to force it (but understand that this will cause code which already ran once to be run again, i.e. any commands which were already there before you edited the file. Usually this is harmless, but we can't know what you have in there).

Answer (score 4):

The killer for me was space and single quotes.
alias test="cd .." worked. 
Don't put any spaces between alias_name=

Answer (score 3):

User level 'system' files need to contain 'plain text'. How to set/configure this for your 'editor-of-choice' can vary (I don't use a Mac so I'm not much help with that.) Soo,

1. create your profile 'from the shell' by appending lines directly, i.e. remove the 'bad lines and then:

   echo "some command string" >> ~/path/bash_profile
2. use 'vi' or 'vim' ##  should be 'safe'
3. review your file via:

   cat -v ~/path/bash_profle | more  ## see any 'funny chars'? or
   cat -ve ~/path/bash_profle | more  ## see any 'funny chars'? or

or

```
vi ~/path/bash_profle # then set 'control codes' to 'on'
set list ## see any 'funny chars' for your 'quotes'?
```

Comment: Option 1 work for me.  After I did that one time, I was able to continue editing and adding new commands in .bash_profile directly in TextEdit without further problems.

Comment: What encoding is 'plain text'? UTF-8?

Comment: The issue was the encoding of the text editor. When I modified the file in VI (OS X) and I saved, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

What I realised is that Mac has option for smart quotes and dashes.
`alias ..='cd ../'` is different from `alias ..=‘cd ../‘`, where the former works but the latter doesn't.

Comment: Maybe highlight that the latter has curly quotes; the difference is not at all clear in some fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can run alias custom auto startup in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.alias_file... by paste file name alias in ~/.bashrc if you use bash or ~/.zshrc if you use zsh.

Ex:

```
if [ -s ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    source ~/.bash_profile;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by editing my .bash_profile in vim  or nano something about text edited messed it up unsure why.

I tried to edit in in notepad just using "open .bash_profile" however something about the symbols translated wrong. So you have to either "vim .bash_profile" or "nano .bash_profile"

Doing this corrected this problem for me.

Comment: Hi Jeremiah, thanks for your answer, however it is a little unclear exactly what you are suggesting. Could you edit your answer to clarify what the 'something' is and what you actually edited to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the alias commands are together in the `.bash_profile` too. That is what was wrong with mine.

Also, if you just type in alias in the terminal, it should list all the known alias commands, so if you don't see your command you know something is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "together"? Their relative order should not matter unless you have code in there which attempts to manipulate already-defined aliases. If you mean "no space on either side of the equals sign" then that's already covered in an earlier answer (and really, it should go without saying that you can't have typos in your code).

Answer (score -1):

If alias is not recognizing, first identify what shell you're using when you open up your terminal or commandlineprompt `echo $SHELL`. For me it's */bin/bash* so i'll input my aliases in `~/.bash_profile`

Take note, the file ~/.bash_profile can store both aliases to call out during a terminal session and autorun those same aliases upon opening up a terminal session. The example below would be to open up a file to edit by text via *vim-software*. You may change it other *text-editors* as you wish. You can see the difference by closure-method.

## ALIAS CALLOUT (*uses parenthesis*)

- alias editbp="vim ~/.bash_profile"

## ALIAS AUTORUN (*uses tilda*)

- alias editbp=`` `vim ~/.bash_profile` ``

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the OP's issue, which seems to be related to bad characters due to the particular editor. Also, this answer directly suggests `~/.bash_profile` which a comment on the original question suggests should not be used, so I think you'd need to address that issue as well.