# Alias defined in .bash_profile not working in OS X

Tags: macos, shell, bash

I have defined three aliases in my `.bash_profile` but my bash shell is not reading it. The aliases defined are not working in my terminal and I couldn't resolve this issue.

```
alias handybook="cd /Users/rsukla/development/repos/handybook/"
```

This line is defined inside the `.bash_profile` but it is not working in my shell.

**Things I have tried so far:**

- I have created `.bashrc` file and defined the alias but it is also not working.
- if I used `source ~rsukla/.bash_profile` then the alias are working fine but I want the alias permanently so I don't have to use `source` every time I open my shell

Any idea why the hell the `alias` are not working in when I define in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: You might consider using [goat](https://github.com/0mp/goat) to manage your shortcut aliases.

Comment: Is `alias` the only command that is not sourcing? How about environmental variables?

Comment: I think the my bash shell is not reading the ~/.bash_profile. But let me check with other commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*We still don't know why aliases are not loaded automatically.*

Your aliases should be loaded from the `.bash_profile`. This is the default behaviour of bash in OS X.

[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/) wrote more about the problem in [their answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511105/4694621).

#### A hacky workaround

Open the **Preferences** of the Terminal. You specify the command you start your shell with:

[image: terminal preferences]

Instead of manually sourcing your dotfiles every time you can specify which file you want to source when the shell opens. Here is the list of options for `bash`:

```
Usage:  bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
    bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
    --debug
    --debugger
    --dump-po-strings
    --dump-strings
    --help
    --init-file
    --login
    --noediting
    --noprofile
    --norc
    --posix
    --protected
    --rcfile
    --restricted
    --verbose
    --version
    --wordexp
Shell options:
    -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option      (invocation only)
    -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option
```

You might consider using `/bin/bash --rcfile alias_file_of_yours` or something similar.

#### Go for [`goat`](https://github.com/0mp/goat) if you need aliases using the `cd` command.

As a side note I do recommend you to check out [goat](https://github.com/0mp/goat). It lets you manage such `cd` aliases easily.

I use it and I wrote it.

Comment: I cannot permanently define alias but I can use `source ~/.bashrc` each time I start a new bash shell to load my alias. Works fine for me

Answer (score 4):

Assuming:

- you use OS X's native terminal, Terminal.app, or popular alternative [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features/hotkey)
- and `bash` is indeed your shell (as is the default on OS X)

then **`~/.bash_profile` *should* be loaded for every interactive shell**, because **both terminal programs create *login* shells by default**.
Bash *login* shells source `~/.bash_profile`, but not `~/.bashrc`.

<sup>Note that this **differs from most *Linux* distros**, where a *single* login shell is executed *on startup*, and later interactive shells are *non-login* shells, which only load `~/.bashrc`, not `~/.bash_profile`.

A frequently seen technique to ensure that definitions are loaded in *both* login and non-login interactive shells is to place definitions in `~/.bashrc`, and then source it from `~/.bash_profile`, using the following line:

`[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc`</sup>

---

You can create a login shell on demand by executing `bash -l` from an existing shell; if that loads your aliases, then the problem must be with what your default shell is and/or how your terminal program is configured.

- `echo $SHELL` tells you what your default shell is.
- if you use Terminal.app, `Terminal > Preferences...`, tab `General`, setting `Shells open with` tells you whether the default shell or a custom shell is being used.