# bash alias in conda environment

Tags: bash, conda

I have an alias in my `.bash_profile` to directly go to my working folder:

```
alias workings='cd desktop/working_folder/'
```

so everytime I type `workings` in `Terminal`, it will `cd desktop/working_folder/`.

But that did not work in the `Terminal` in `conda`:

> bash: workings: command not found

I believe in `conda` case, the `.bash_profile` is somewhere else, but I cannot locate it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using An Exported Function Instead

If instead of an alias you create an *exported function*, it will be available to all instances of bash that inherit environment variables from a shell in which it was exported.

```
workings() { cd ~/desktop/working_folder/; };
export -f workings
```

---

#### Alternately: Selecting The Right Dotfiles

In general, on UNIX, `~/.bash_profile` (and its predecessor `~/.profile`) are run only for *login shells*. Traditionally, each session has only one login shell, and future terminal windows run *non-login interactive shells* (which source `~/.bashrc` instead).

Thus, for traditionally-configured UNIX systems, you'd need to put aliases in `~/.bashrc`, not `~/.profile`, for them to have effect in regular graphical terminals opened after starting a graphical session.

MacOS, however, is *not* such a traditional system: *All* terminal windows start login shells, which is why putting an alias in `~/.bash_profile` usually works... until you're running a shell that *wasn't* directly started by your terminal program.

Thus, best practice is to do both of the below:

- Move aliases and non-exported variables / shell runtime settings / etc from `~/.bash_profile` to `~/.bashrc`
- Source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` so those definitions are still available in regular terminals

For more on this, see [@mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511105/14122) on [Alias defined in .bash_profile not working in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484139/alias-defined-in-bash-profile-not-working-in-os-x)